# Making Readonly all fields in a form

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can we make all fields in a form  read only ?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This should work:

```
$(':input').attr('readonly','readonly');
```

Or if you have a specific form...

```
$('#myFormID :input').attr('readonly','readonly');
```

If you are using just plain JavaScript, you'll want to do this.

```
var f = document.forms['myFormNAME'];
for(var i=0,fLen=f.length;i<fLen;i++){
  f.elements[i].readOnly = true;//As @oldergod noted, the "O" must be upper case
}
```

One side note... although you can "set" the readonly flag on `checkbox` and `hidden` input fields... it won't actually *make* them readonly.

Comment: if I want to do only by javascript?

Comment: Why put jquery in the tags then.

Comment: `if I want to do only by javascript` you should learn JavaScript :)

Comment: `f.elements[i].readonly = true;` => `f.elements[i].readOnly = true;`

Comment: @oldergod using the lowercase property name `readonly` (matching how it would be set in the HTML) is perfectly fine.  The only issue with case sensitivity is with IE's bugs in the `setAttribute()` method as documented here: http://webbugtrack.blogspot.ca/2007/08/bug-242-setattribute-doesnt-always-work.html for "dual word" attribute names in older IE versions the name needed to be `firstSecond` camel cased.

Comment: The upper code did not work with neither IE or Chrome for me and worked once I set the upcased 'O'. I am not top familiar with Js but it was I had to do to make it work here.

Comment: Thanks @oldergod I stand corrected.  Somehow in my original testing I thought I had the lower case but actually had the upper case.

Answer (score 2):

A solution without javascript, enclose all fields in fieldsets and add `disabled` tag to fieldsets.

Comment: Way better solution plus it suggests good practice by using `fieldset` to group related inputs